# Is the docker image identifier available to the process(es) running inside that docker?

Tags: docker

For my logs, I'd like to include the docker image identifier so that way I can later reconsil the external logs with the image that generated them.

Is there a way for a process inside a docker to get the image identifier it is running into? Maybe a `/dev/...` or  `/proc/...` file?

Comment: That data is not exposed inside the container (unless you were to pass it in explicitly as an environment variable).

Comment: I'd expect whoever's collecting the logs on the outside to know the image name. For example, if you use `docker logs` you know which container you're querying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's been discussions on injecting metadata like this over in OCI, and previously in various individual runtimes like docker. However, at present, no capability to do this on any arbitrary container exists. It would be up to you creating the container to include the necessary metadata.

- https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec/issues/1105
- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8427

Realize there may be security risks depending on how much metadata you give the container. E.g. this data may help an attacker within the container to predict filesystem locations on the host, which could then be leveraged in vulnerabilities like [GHSA-c3xm-pvg7-gh7r](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/security/advisories/GHSA-c3xm-pvg7-gh7r).

Comment: As I was writing my question, I was thinking that security could be viewed as an issue. I'm not too sure how it could really help from within the chroot environment, but I'm not that familiar with that type of potential issues.